# How do I test for TrueCrypt?

Tags: 11.10, encryption, truecrypt

I'm fairly certain my Ubuntu 11.10 install has truecrypt for my home directory, but how can I check. Preferably without rebooting into a live disk install?

Answer (score 2):

The command

```
mount | awk '$3 == "'"$HOME"'"'
```

would give you an output line if your home is a mounpoint, with information about the type of filesystem. This should also allow to detect a truecrypt home folder.

Answer (score 0):

If your home directory is encrypted (not truecrypted, there is difference), you can tell by looking for `~/.Private` and `~/.ecryptfs` in `ls -la`: `ls -la | grep ".Private"` for example.